# Что правда, то правда. Члены предложения

Tags: члены-предложения

Если это законченное предложение, то каково оно по составу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это так называемое "нечленимое предложение" — предложение, выраженное одним словом или устойчивым словосочетанием. Нечленимые предложения не относятся к односоставным или двусоставным предложениям и не включают в себя какие-либо главные или второстепенные члены.

Сочетание "что правда, то правда" - частица.